# In tokio-tungstenite next cause exit

Tags: asynchronous, rust, rust-tokio

I am using tokio-tungstenite to access a server.
Unfortunately, the read operation does not work and the program exits with error code 0 so a priori no error. A simplified code (the "..." are not what I used though) would be

```
use tokio_tungstenite::connect_async;
use futures_util::StreamExt;
use futures_util::SinkExt;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
  let url_name = "wss://...";
  let (ws_stream, _) = connect_async(url_name).await.unwrap();
  let (mut write, mut read) = ws_stream.split();
  tokio::spawn(async move {
    let ent = read.next().await;
    println!("We have ent");
  });
  write.send(tokio_tungstenite::tungstenite::Message::Text("...".to_string())).await;
}
```

The behavior of buggy program I would expect is either the read hanging out or the **ent** being **None** or if not None containing the error inside of it that I could interpret. But no the program exits without error messages.

Besides the immediate issue of what is wrong, what could be a debugging approach for understanding what is happening in tokio?

Comment: What if you add a `tokio::delay` after the write? Looks like the program executes the write and then ends before finishing the read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program exits after the `write.send(...)` future yields a result. This result is discarded, so it doesn't influence the exit code of your program.

The compiler actually emits a warning for unused results, hinting that you should be handling that.

If you want to bubble up the error state of your write operation, you can `unwrap()` the result returned by it. If writing to the underlying WebSocket fails, your program will panic and exit.

If the write operation succeeds and you want to wait for the read operation, you'll need to bind the `JoinHandle` returned by `tokio::spawn` to a variable and await it, i.e.

```
  let handle = tokio::spawn(async move {
    let ent = read.next().await.expect("Stream ended").expect("Error while reading");
    println!("We have ent");
  });
    write.send(tokio_tungstenite::tungstenite::Message::Text("...".to_string())).await.expect("Failed to write the message");
  handle.await.expect("The read task failed.");
```

The `handle`'s future will return an error if the underlying task panicked, which would be the case if the read operation failed.

Comment: Thank you. This resolves the problem. What I missed is that the compiler did not return a warning when I wrote **tokio::spawn**. It did not indicate that some variable was discarded.

Comment: `JoinHandle` is not annotated with `#[must_use]` while `Result` has this annotation. The whole point about `tokio::spawn` is to be able to create a task that runs independently from the code following the callsite. Iirc, it also enables true parallelism when working with a multi-threaded runtime. It's pretty common to discard that `JoinHandle` without ever awaiting it. Thus adding this annotation would be super noisy and annoying.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the explanation. Still feels that I somehow fell into a crack and do not know if there is a more systematic way of detecting this kind of problem. Here, you helped, and I thank you for it. In a more complex system, looks like it might be much harder.

Comment: You can create your own wrapper around `tokio::spawn` that adds the annotation: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=03451c7a22a9ac6b1a18d94e2e71345d